# Php API Returning whole object instead of Just message

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, api

Hey I wrote a rest api using PHP for insertion of data. I tried to render the message into my ajax success response but I am getting nothing in response instead a bunch of whole objects.

my php return code

```
if(mysqli_query($connection , $ins)){


    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Item Added' , 'status' => true));

}else{

    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Failed to add item' , 'status' => false));

}
```

And this is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({

            url : "http://localhost/cokeinventory/rest-api/api-insert-item.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify({

                    item:itemname , unit:unit , date:expdate , bcode:bcode , blabel:blabel
            }),
            error:err=>{
                console.log(err)
            },
            success:function(data){
              console.log(data.message);
            }
        });   
    });
```

And this is I am getting in my response
[image]

Comment: if(mysqli_query($connection , $ins)){
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Item Added' , 'status' => true));
    exit();
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Failed to add item' , 'status' => false));
}

Comment: How is this question related to HTML?

Comment: And what's your question about this code? Is this a PHP problem, or a jQuery problem? Please remove the tags that are irrelevant for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Exit after echo it is displaying these string because it is present in html

```
if(mysqli_query($connection , $ins)){
     echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Item Added' , 'status' => true));
     exit();
 }else{
   echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Failed to add item' , 'status' => false));
    exit();
 }
```

and use json decode

```
$.ajax({

            url : "http://localhost/cokeinventory/rest-api/api-insert-item.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : JSON.stringify({

                    item:itemname , unit:unit , date:expdate , bcode:bcode , blabel:blabel
            }),
            error:err=>{
                console.log(err)
            },
            success:function(data){
             var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
              console.log(obj.message);
            }
        });   
    });
```

Comment: You don't have to echo the response and exit the request. That's what `return` stands for

Comment: why you forcing him to return json response? he asked simple question he need message in success response.

Comment: Because that is what you should do in programming. Follow standards and principles, do not mess up application. That is how OOP structured

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli it didnt worked its still sending me the whole bunch of object

Comment: It is not related to php. It is jquery problem.

Comment: actually i wrote the api in PHP thats why i mentioned php in tag sorry for that but can u help

Comment: okay cool i figured it out
i just had to add  dataType: 'json', in my ajax call and its working